# @baseDir variable not working in less file for background-image. Says undefined

Tags: magento2, less

Several other questions/answers here say to use the variable @{baseDir} to get the URL for background-image. I added this to my themes less file, however, when I compile, it crashes.

variable @baseDir is undefined

I do not understand how to proceed. I found several other files that have the reference to baseDir and it works fine, but in this specific less file, it doesn't. Frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the mixins and variables are defined in `lib/web/css/source/lib` and `pub/static/frontend/{vendor-name}/{theme-name}/en_US/css/source/lib`.

So I added the following import in
`app/design/frontend/{vendor-name}/{theme-name}/web/css/source/_extend.less`:

```
@import 'lib/_lib';
...
```

This import contains the definitions of variables and mixins of various less files inside lib.
In my case, I was trying to change the minicart icon to a svg put in web/images. I wanted to use the `.lib-icon-image()` mixin which has `${baseDir}` in its first argument. I was getting `$baseDir` is undefined because it did not come across any `$baseDir: 'path'` declaration before. Then I hard-coded the `@{baseDir}` in the `.lib-icon-image()` mixin and I got `.lib-icon-image` is undefined. Then I realized that the neither the variable nor the mixin is defined in my custom theme and then I imported `lib/_lib` and it compiled without issues. This took me hours.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Please use the base URL like this

First add image in `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\web\images` folder and write css as below:

```
background: url('@{baseDir}images/icon_sprite.png');
```

after add new image run command as below:

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

if it's helpful please accept it, Thanks